# How to set 2 characters as wrap character?

Tags: csv, xsd, biztalk

How to create a BizTalk Flat File XSD-schema for csv-file, which uses two quotes ("") as wrap-character and has wraped every row data (except header) with the same single character (")?

For example:

```
header1,header2,header3,header4
"text1,""68,12"",""32,11"",""69,38"""
"text2,,""13,71"",""123,56"""
"text3,""12,75"",,""732,87"""
"text4,""147,14"",""65,43"","
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?  Your question is too broad and will be closed as such unless you improve it substantially.

Comment: @kjhughes   He is basically stuck because you can't specify multiple characters for a wrap character in a BizTalk Flat file schema to parse that payload, although that isn't obvious to someone without BizTalk knowledge, I've edited the question to make that clearer, and voted to re-open.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: Thanks for improving the question.  I've voted to re-open upon your recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Flat File Schema Wizard.

1) By delimiter symbol

[image: By delimiter symbol]

2) CR LF

[image: CR LF]

3) Record the Header and Repeating Record the first item]

[image: Record the Header and Repeating Record the first item]

4) By delimiter symbol ","

[image: By delimiter symbol ","]

...

Comment: With header there isn't any problems. If you try to create xsd-scheme and set wrap-character - you'll be faced with problem. Wrap character must be a CHARACTER, not STRING

Comment: Your problem is also that you have a start " character and an end " character by record. Maybe you have to do this in two steps, first generating an intermediate XML for examplo: <Root xmlns="http://BizTalkMassCopy.FlatFileSchema4">
 <Root_Child1 xmlns="">
  <Root_Child1_Child1>header1</Root_Child1_Child1> ...
  </Root_Child1>
 <Root_Child2 xmlns="">
  <Field>text1,"68,12","32,11","69,38"</Field> 
  </Root_Child2>
... and then within a map, generate your correct XML.

Comment: Thanks. I have done it successfully in two steps, as you have adviced

Answer (score 1):

That just isn't a valid CSV structure*, so you are going to have problems getting it 100% right.

*As some of your commas are inside the quotes and no quotes between sets of commas

The closest schema I could create that would parse that successfully is below, where I treat the quote as the delimiter for the lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.46099894" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.46099894" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="Root" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="postfix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="Root_Child1">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="," child_order="infix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Root_Child1_Child1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Root_Child1_Child2" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Root_Child1_Child3" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Root_Child1_Child4" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="4" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Root_Child2">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="&quot;" child_order="infix" sequence_number="2" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Root_Child2_Child1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Which gives the following result

```
<Root xmlns="http://Scratch.46099894">
    <Root_Child1 xmlns="">
        <Root_Child1_Child1>header1</Root_Child1_Child1>
        <Root_Child1_Child2>header2</Root_Child1_Child2>
        <Root_Child1_Child3>header3</Root_Child1_Child3>
        <Root_Child1_Child4>header4</Root_Child1_Child4>
    </Root_Child1>
    <Root_Child2 xmlns="">
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>text1,</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>68,12</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>,</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>32,11</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>,</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>69,38</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
    </Root_Child2>
    <Root_Child2 xmlns="">
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>text2,,</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>13,71</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>,</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>123,56</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
    </Root_Child2>
    <Root_Child2 xmlns="">
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>text3,</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>12,75</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>,,</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>732,87</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
    </Root_Child2>
    <Root_Child2 xmlns="">
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>text4,</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>147,14</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>,</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>65,43</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child1>,</Root_Child2_Child1>
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
    </Root_Child2>
</Root>
```

But possibly you should be getting whatever is creating these files to format them correctly in the first place.

e.g.

```
header1,header2,header3,header4
"text1","68,12","32,11","69,38"
"text2","","13,71","123,56"
"text3","12,75","","732,87"
"text4","147,14","65,43",""
```

Comment: This schema gets correct numbers, but result isn't correct.

Comment: You are going to have to be a bit more specific about what isn't correct, otherwise we can't help you.    As I said, your payload isn't correctly formatted, and unless you write a custom pipeline component to pre-parse it, you aren't going to be able to do it with a schema alone.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help. I mean the result must be something like this (for first row): 
       `<Root_Child2 xmlns="">`
        `<Root_Child2_Child1>text1</Root_Child2_Child1>`
        `<Root_Child2_Child1>68,12</Root_Child2_Child1>`
        `<Root_Child2_Child1>32,11</Root_Child2_Child1>`
        `<Root_Child2_Child1>69,38</Root_Child2_Child1>`
       `</Root_Child2>`

Comment: @Vitaliy Can you push back at whoemever is creating these files and get them to format them correctly as CSV file?